# Доработать шаблон сайта для мобильных устройств

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, мобильная-разработка

Есть сайт с версткой для десктопов. Естественно в мобильных устройствах он не смотрится от слова вообще. Также вебмастера Гугла и Яндекса ругаются на несоответствие. Познания в верстке под мобильные устройства отсутствуют, поэтому два вопроса:

1) Как и с помощью каких средств и инструментов достаточно просто "доработать" существующий дизайн под адаптивный вариант?

2) Какие средства и инструменты использовать при верстке новых сайтов?

Answer (score 0):

1) bootstrap, flex, grid
2) bootstrap, flex, grid

Comment: для существующей верстки без bootstrap можно ли обойтись инструкциями @media only screen and ... ?

Comment: @Ruport без бутстрапа всегда можно. Кто что использует, кому что нравится. Я не пользуюсь бутстрапом, пользуюсь `@media` при необходимости

Comment: @Ruport , цена количества и читаемости кода

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с тем, что такое @media-запросы. 
Я делаю так: верстаю под десктоп сначала, а потом меняю окно браузера под нужное разрешение и в соответствующем @media с помощью Chrome натягиваю верстку.

Comment: а как быть с современными телефонами с большим разрешением? например у меня huawei p30. Экран 2340х1080 точек. 1080px по горизонтали для монитора это примерно 30см, а для телефона всего лишь 6,5см. И то что на мониторе для @media...1000 смотрится нормально, то же самое в телефоне лупой не разглядеть. Как быть?

Comment: Опять же обопрусь на свой опыт. Если элементов много, делаем три верстки - до 768 пикселей, до 1200 и свыше. От 769 до 1200 делайте просто элементы побольше.